# Ubuntu appears very small at 1080p, text almost undreadable

Tags: display, fonts, display-resolution

I have a 15" Dell Studio XPS with a 1080p screen. Everything seems tiny with 1080p, in 720p everything is fine but just looks very low-res.

So I definitely want to get the full resolution the display can give me but don't want everything so small.

**EDIT:**

Well, yes higher resolution means more pixels. But it shouldn't mean fonts the size of 7 in MS word, and web pages looking like there at 50%...

[image: Screenshot 1.]
[image: Screenshot 2.]

I'm not saying windows is better, but windows did not appear miniature at 1080p.

Comment: small? that's kind of the point of a higher resolution, can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: That is kind of the point; higher resolution = smaller pixels.

Comment: Do you know what a screenshot is? you hit the "print screen" button and then upload it!

Comment: For vote to closers: OP is asking for a way to scale the entire UI. This is a valid question and should not be closed in my opinion.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using Ubuntu Tweak you can adjust the Text Scaling Factor. Increasing the value will increase text size system wide.

The setting can be found in `Ubuntu Tweak<Tweaks<Fonts`

[image]

If you don't have Ubuntu Tweak installed it can be installed by downloading the [.deb file](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/138267532/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.4-1_all.deb) here, or you can run these commands in the Terminal:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/next`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

Answer (score 17):

Try this: Open "System Settings" then from "System" section select "Universal Access". On  the first tab marked "Seeing" there is a drop-down field marked "Text size". Adjust the text size to Large or Larger.

Comment: I have tried other stuff before, like the tweak tool or adjuting each thing (firefox, terminal, etc). This fully solved my problem. The best approach.

Comment: this is the correct answer!

Comment: what about KDE?

Comment: Thanks. This is the best one!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with an Asus Zenbook UX303UB.
Couldn't change it [neither with](http://www.zdnet.com/article/linus-torvalds-reveals-his-favorite-programming-laptop/)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
```

[nor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbook#LCD) with `xrandr --dpi 138/eDP1`, but:

***For GNOME Shell** (17.10+)*:Settings > Devices > Displays, 200%

[image: screenshot]

***For Unity** (17.04-)*: All settings > Display, on *Scale for menu and title bars* set to **2**.

[image: Ubuntu display settings panel]

However, some programs still look small.

Comment: You saved me. I don't know how to thank you.

Comment: yes, it works for me. Thank you. As you said, some programs still look small, and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @HuiZheng  Which programs did you found still looking small? Maybe we could find a pattern, a workaround or fix; I would add it to my post.  I don't remember of any program whit this issue lately.

Answer (score 2):

just go to settings > accessibilty > Large Text -this will chage the size to windows like if you are partiularly looking for this.