# Font is too small in Ubuntu 20.04.03

Tags: fonts

I bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu 20.04.03, then I changed the theme to look like MAC.

For some reason the adress of the URL in chrome (and other browsers) is too small.

[image: URL browser too small]

I tried changing the fonts via using the Tweaks following [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/314494/ubuntu-appears-very-small-at-1080p-text-almost-undreadable), but it did not fix the problem.

[image: Tweaks - Fonts menu]

My PC configuration:

[image: PC configuration]

update I tried [large text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wio2O.png) and it did not fix the problem .

Comment: Did you look at the Chrome settings?

Comment: yes I did ,did not fix the problem . also the buttens are very small .

Comment: Revert the fonts to their default sizes and try to change the *Scaling Factor* in Tweaks -> *Fonts*.

Comment: You can also scale all the UI up by going to Settings -> *Universal Access* and toggling *Large Text*. If any of these works, please tell me so I can write a proper answer.

Comment: GNOME does not handle themes very well. Some work better than others. GNOME devs have chosen a "worse is better" approach to the UI design.  If you want more fine-tuned control over the elements of the UI, consider using a different [flavour](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) like Kubuntu or Xubuntu.  You can "Try Ubuntu" from installation media so you do not have to change your installed system unless/until you are ready

Comment: I tried this .still does not work

Comment: @tomer The last screenshot you added does not show the top bar. Toggling *Large Text* should have made it larger. You can try restarting GNOME Shell by pressing `Alt`+`F2`, entering `r` and pressing `Enter` to make sure that the changes are applied. If everything else except the top bar is OK, please let me know. I can provide a workaround for the top bar to increase its font size.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Try this command in terminal.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
```

If the value appeared on terminal is 1, your scaling factor is 100%.

Then, use this command.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.3
```

1.3 means your scaling factor will be set to 130%, therefore larger fonts will be displayed.

You can change 1.3 on the command above to whatever scale you like.

**Method 2**

Try other commands in terminal.

```
xrandr | grep " connected"
```

If you see like

```
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
```

on terminal, this means your display is eDP-1.

Then, type the command as follows in terminal.

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.8x0.8
```

I wrote eDP-1 because my display is eDP-1, so change it to your display name.

Also, you can change 0.8 on the command above to adjust your font and button size.

In this command, unlikely the Method 1, the smaller the value is, the larger the font and buttons are.

Comment: I tried what you suggested how ever it also does work... I am ready to try other form of GNOME. any suggestions ?

Comment: I tried this and it also looks good to me.
https://askubuntu.com/a/67260/1125695

FIrstly, try `gsettings get...` command and then use `gsettings set...` command. 
Does this work?